# URL formatting using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, pretty-urls

I want to hide `shop` if I have `bill` after that:

These are my sample URLs:

```
http://mypools.myfiles.com/shop/bill/home.php
http://mypools.myfiles.com/shop/bill/search.php
http://mypools.myfiles.com/shop/bill/index.php
```

Also, if I type any of the following URLs:

```
http://mypools.myfiles.com/shop/bill
http://mypools.myfiles.com/shop/bill/
```

I want it to redirect to the following link:

```
http://mypools.myfiles.com/shop/bill/home.php
```

Comment: Why would someone eat your URLs?

Comment: There are some ambiguities in your question: Do you want to redirect `http://mypools.myfiles.com/bill/home.php` to `http://mypools.myfiles.com/shop/bill/home.php` (internally) and `http://mypools.myfiles.com/shop/bill` to `http://mypools.myfiles.com/shop/bill/home.php` internally or externally?

Comment: Sorry for confusion. Main requirement is to hide "shop" from first three url (should work on all similar urls). if i type "http://mypools.myfiles.com/shop/bill" OR "http://mypools.myfiles.com/shop/bill/" it should redirect to http://mypools.myfiles.com/shop/bill/home.php [ but shop will not display in final url ]. Is it clear now ?

Answer (score 1):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(bill/.+)$ /shop/$1 [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^shop/bill/?$ /shop/bill/home.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: Above code is for redirecting ....../bill/  to .../bill/home.php   OR  hide shop folder from uRL?

Comment: This code is for handling `http://mypools.myfiles.com/shop/search.php` URL in your browser that will be rewritten internally to `http://mypools.myfiles.com/shop/bill/search.php`